# Can I use Android studio 3.0, Lifecycles, ViewModel and LiveData for now?

Tags: android

I have a new Android project which should be done by November (2 months), and I'm considering using Android studio 3.0 and the new Architecture components like ViewModel and LiveData.

The application needs to support Android 4 Kitkat and above.

Can I use them without any problem? or better not using for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final preview of Android Oreo is already out and so I think there should not be any problem using the new Architecture components.

Once these new Architecture Components are included in support library, all you need to do is extend the activity back to AppCompatActivity.